# Porqué NUITKA al generar el fichero exe incluye siempre cerca de 1200 ficheros referentes al módulo pytz?

Tags: python-3.x, pytz, nuitka

Recientemente he empezado a compilar algunos de mis scripts en python para pasarlos a un exe y poder usarlos luego en equipos donde no está python instalado.

Veo que en todas las ocasiones me genera una serie de 1200 ficheros referidos al módulo pytz. Este módulo no incluyo en ninguno de los ficheros que componen la aplicación y no entiendo porqué se incluyen.

No es que me influya en el funcionamiento de la aplicación, pero al comprimir toda la carpeta "dist" que se genera termina por haber un montón de ficheros que luego en un equipo con pocos recursos cuesta un tiempo enorme para descomprimir y sustituir en la carpeta destino donde actualiza la versión anterior de la aplicación.

Comando nuitka:

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --windows-icon-from-ico=icon.ico --output-dir="c:\app.distribution\test" .\app.py
```

Y esto es lo que genera por pantalla al terminar todo el proceso:

```
Nuitka-Options:INFO: Used command line options: --standalone --windows-icon-from-ico=icon.ico --output-dir=c:\app.distribution\test .\app.py
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '1.8.4' on Python '3.11' commercial grade 'not installed'.
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: cl (cl 14.3).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend linking program with 765 files (no progress information available for this stage).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Compiled 765 C files using clcache with 765 cache hits and 0 cache misses.
Nuitka-Postprocessing:INFO: Adding 1 icon(s) from icon file 'icon.ico'.
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: data-files: Included data file 'Crypto\Util\.keep_dir.txt' due to empty dir needed for 'Crypto.Util._raw_api'.
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: data-files: Included data file 'certifi\cacert.pem' due to package data for 'certifi'.
**Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: data-files: Included 602 data files due to package data directory 'zoneinfo' for 'pytz'.
**Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: data-files: Included 602 data files due to package data directory '.' for 'tzdata.zoneinfo'.
Nuitka:INFO: Keeping build directory 'c:\app.distribution\test\app.build'.
Nuitka:INFO: Successfully created 'c:\app.distribution\test\app.dist\app.exe'.
```

Las dos filas con los asteriscos son las que no logro adivinar porqué se generan siempre y son las que me gustaría poder excluir de la generación del exe porque como digo, luego toda la carpeta "dist" tiene 1500 ficheros y 1200 son relativos a este módulo y los ficheros son todos de nombres de ciudades, países y tendrán que ver con la gestión horaria seguramente pero en mi aplicación no hago uso de nada de todo esto, únicamente del módulo nativo datetime

Comment: ¿Alguno de los paquetes que usas en el proyecto tiene pytz como dependencia directa o  indirecta?

Comment: Es probable que sí. Justo ayer en un equipo nuevo tuve que instalar varios módulos de python para poder ejecutar el script desde el propio intérprete y me di cuenta que uno de ellos (no me quedé con la copla del nombre del módulo) hizo que automáticamente se instalara pytz y tzone... lo cual ya me dio la pista de que mi duda podría estar provocada por este tema.